# Launch a new shell from C

Tags: c, shell

How do I launch a new non-interactive shell process from C?

Currently I have the following:

```
system(cmdStr);
//system("/bin/sh -c");
```

The cmdStr is the command I want to execute. I have the reference below to the shell process... but how do I append the cmdStr to it? How do I make it launch a new process?

Comment: system() does execute `/bin/sh -c <command>`. What do you mean by "non-interactive"?

Comment: `system` is a bad idea since you'll have to think about how escaping works, which may differ from shell to shell.  On Unix, `fork` + `execve` (and others) is the way to go.  On Windows, `CreateProcess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to concatenate the string, you can do:

```
if (fork())
{
    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", cmdStr, (char *) NULL);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```

which is what `system` basically does.

Otherwise to a concatenate a string, you should have a look to standard functions `strcat` and `strncat` from `string.h`.

Comment: I am getting "Implicit declaration of function 'exec' is invalid in C99"